# I am seeking a Solaris 8 patch file

Tags: solaris

I have a question. Our company's server uses the Solaris 8. I am seeking a Solaris 8 patch file. The patch file name is 'withdrawn patch 110910-04 or 05'. And current patch version is 'withdrawn patch 110910-01'. I could not find a patch file from the 'support.oracle.com'. Please tell me where to get the patch file. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Solaris patches are available on [support.oracle.com](https://support.oracle.com/) to customers with an Oracle Solaris support contract.

However, 'withdrawn patch 110910-04105' is not a valid Solaris patch name, even for a withdrawn patch - you can't find it because someone gave you the wrong name.

Comment: You are right.
I wrote the wrong patch name.
The actual patch name is 'withdrawn patch 110910-04 or 05'.
And the current patch version is 'withdrawn patch 110910-01'.
I could not find a patch file from the 'support.oracle.com'.
Ask for advice from other methods.
Thank you.

Comment: You should be so polite to read the [help→tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) especially the part about no-distractions, no chit-chat. "I have a question" really, no one would have guessed if you had not written that. Having to read "Thank your for reading." is wasting time for every person looking at your question.

Comment: 'withdrawn' means it has been made unavailable.   Oracle is the copyright owner of the patch, if you cannot acquire it from them via support, then other methods would be copyright violations, and not up for discussion on this site.